# What is the connotation of "who wouldn't want to be"?

Tags: grammar

Yesterday I talked to my colleague. I was saying that if someone got hired by a company, make sure this guy got job A rather than job B. Then my colleague asked me, "Who wouldn't want to take job A?" Did my colleague mean that everyone, given job A and job B available, would always go for job A?

The funny thing is I am having job B. Did my colleague try to make it condescending towards me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like he thinks Job A is the better job, maybe because it's easier or pays more. But I don't think he meant it in a condescending way; he just likes job A